# Return Promise From REST Call

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, promise, ionic2

I'm trying to invoke a REST call and return a promise so I can manipulate the data afterwhich.

```
var self = this;
var returnPromise;
returnPromise = self.httpService.testService();
returnPromise.then(function(result){
 console.log(result);
});
```

My REST service is located **in another file** which has the following:

```
 testService() {
    console.log("start of testService");

    var request = require('request');
    var user = "test";
    var ipadd = "127.0.0.1";

    request({

        url: 'https://' + 'LocalHost' + '/URLOFWEBSERVICE',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: {
            userID: user,
            userIpAddress: ipadd
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode, body);
            var newPro = new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
                fulfill(body);
            });

            console.log(newPro);
            return newPro;

        }
    });
}
```

I'm able to print out response.stateCode , body( REST result) and the "invoked fulfill" console is printed out.

The problem lies with the

> returnPromise.then

in the **first page**, in which **".then"** returns me undefined.

At first I thought that it might be the promise has been called before the REST returns me a response. So, I thought of doing a timeout function to test.

```
setTimeout(
function(){
  console.log(returnPromise);
}
, 5000);
```

But even so, returnPromise returns me "undefined".

Comment: you need to post the source code of `testService()` at least.

Comment: what is `self.httpService.testService();` returning? a Promise? ... is `.then` undefined or is `result` in .then callback undefined?

Comment: _"My REST service is located in another file which has the following:"_ Is `javascript` at "in another file" within a function that is called?

Comment: Lemme reorg the codes! Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you expecting `self.httpService.testService();` to return a rejected promise object? Have you tried chaining `.catch()` to `returnPromise`?

Comment: testService doesn't return anything - not even a Promise

Comment: @guest271314 im trying to get the response of the HTTPS call to my main page.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm able to get a response 200 and my data from response.statusCode, body

Comment: regardless, testService doesn't return anything - not even a Promise

Comment: probably @guest271314 - that's the normal thing to do, though from the code shown, there's no indication of what should happen in such an event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expect a function to return a promise, it should return a promise

your testService does not return anything

this does:

```
testService() {
    console.log("start of testService");
    var request = require('request');
    var user = "test";
    var ipadd = "127.0.0.1";
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        request({
            url: 'https://' + 'LocalHost' + '/URLOFWEBSERVICE',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            form: {
                userID: user,
                userIpAddress: ipadd
            }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                // reject the promise, handle with .catch
                reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log(response.statusCode, body);
                fulfill(body);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

That can be called as

```
// var self = this; // why? not needed in the code shown
// var returnPromise; // why? it's not needed in the code shown

this.httpService.testService()
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // handle your errors here
});
```

Comment: ahhh I didn't know my promise didn't actually return one. Thanks!

Comment: you mean your function didn't return one :p